# Why does ObservableObject in MVVM-Light no longer implement INotifyPropertyChanging?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I have been using `ObservableObject` and some other classes that derive from it, e.g `ViewModelBase`.
I updated to version 5.0.1.31549. And it seems that ObserableObject no longer implements the `INotifyPropertyChanging`.

Is there a reason for this? Is there alternative classes to use, or should I implement the interface, and related methods like `RaisePropertyChanging()` myself?

Comment: It's strange, that it was implemented it... While `INotifyPropertyChanged` is one of corner stones of data binding concept, `INotifyPropertyChanging` is pretty useless. May be, they just dropped yet another rudiment in new version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reason is probably because PCL projects do not support `INotifyPropertyChanging` and MvvmLight has most of it's base code moved to a PCL project to support desktop and mobile devices. You can see it [commented in the source](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest). You'd need to browse to `ObservableObject`. can't seem to link it directly. "GalaSoft.MvvmLight -> GalaSoft.MvvmLight (PCL) -> ObservableObject.cs"

```
public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged /*, INotifyPropertyChanging*/
```

You can also see this answer for an [alternate approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15526811/1834662) you could use to implement what you need yourself.

Do note that it still implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `ViewModelBase` still derives from `ObservableObject`, so in most cases they should be fine for your desktop or mobile devices using MvvmLight.